# Unable to resolve serialized item error during Unicorn sync task while setting up Habitat

Tags: habitat

I am trying to setup Sitecore Habitat but getting some wiered issue when the Unicorn sync starts.
I have all the steps performed as mentioned in the below link,
https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started

Also the following is the error,

```html
[11:17:27] Starting '05-Sync-Unicorn'...
Sync-Unicorn: Preparing authorization for http://habitat.dev.local/unicorn.aspx?verb=Sync&configuration=


Sync-Unicorn: Received challenge: 94efeb736a614746b51d29c857f66ada


Sync-Unicorn: Created signature y3NWBOy9Li4xncvmYFqHDux1trU0VMHneYV8IABgGweBCu1HyeEEtjFm25IaIg82LeMnCHbX/G1VeEx5uhvNMA==, executing Sync...


Error: Invoke-WebRequest : Sync Unicorn

Error: Info: Foundation.Serialization is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/system/Settings/Project. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need to
perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Foundation. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need to
perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Project. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need to
perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/branches/Foundation. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you

Error: need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?

Error: Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Foundation. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you

Error: Info: Completed.

Error: At C:\projects\scripts\Unicorn\Unicorn.psm1:43 char:12
+ ...   $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers @{ "X-MC-MAC" = $sig ...

Error: +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException

Error:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

C:\projects\scripts\unicorn.js:44
    if (err !== null) throw err;
                      ^

Error: Command failed: powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted "C:\projects\scripts/Unicorn/./Sync.ps1 -secret 749CABBC85EAD20CE55E2C6066F1BE375D2115696C8A8B24DB6ED1FD60613086 -url http://habitat.dev.local/unicorn.aspx"
Invoke-WebRequest : Sync Unicorn
Info: Foundation.Serialization is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/system/Settings/Project. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need to
perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Foundation. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need to
perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Project. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need to
perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/branches/Foundation. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Info: Foundation.Multisite roles are being synced.
Info: Foundation.Multisite role sync complete.
Info: Foundation.Theming is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Theming. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/system/settings/Foundation/Theming. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped.
Perhaps you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Foundation.Theming had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Foundation.Theming sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 1ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info: Feature.Accounts is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Accounts. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/Accounts. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped.
Perhaps you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path core:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Accounts. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/Accounts. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.Accounts had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.Accounts sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 2ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Feature.Accounts roles are being synced.
Info: Feature.Accounts role sync complete.
Info: Feature.Demo is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Demo. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/Demo. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/layouts/Feature/Demo. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/Demo. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.Demo had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.Demo sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 1ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Feature.Demo roles are being synced.
Info: Feature.Demo role sync complete.
Info: Feature.Language is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/Language. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped.
Perhaps you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Language. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/Language. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.Language had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.Language sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 2ms (~3.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Feature.Language roles are being synced.
Info: Feature.Language role sync complete.
Info: Feature.Maps is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path core:/sitecore/system/Field types/Maps. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need to
perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/system/settings/Feature/Maps. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Maps. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/Maps. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/Maps. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.Maps had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.Maps sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 2ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Feature.Maps roles are being synced.
Info: Feature.Maps role sync complete.
Info: Feature.Media is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Media. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/Media. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Media. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/Media. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.Media had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.Media sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 2ms (~3.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Feature.Media roles are being synced.
Info: Feature.Media role sync complete.
Info: Feature.Multisite is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Multisite. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/Multisite. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped.
Perhaps you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/Multisite. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.Multisite had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.Multisite sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 1ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Feature.Multisite roles are being synced.
Info: Feature.Multisite role sync complete.
Info: Feature.Navigation is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Navigation. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/Navigation. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped.
Perhaps you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/Navigation. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.Navigation had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.Navigation sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 1ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Feature.Navigation roles are being synced.
Info: Feature.Navigation role sync complete.
Info: Feature.News is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/News. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/News. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/News. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.News had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.News sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 2ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Feature.News roles are being synced.
Info: Feature.News role sync complete.
Info: Feature.PageContent is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/PageContent. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/PageContent. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped.
Perhaps you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/PageContent. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.PageContent had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.PageContent sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 1ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Feature.PageContent roles are being synced.
Info: Feature.PageContent role sync complete.
Info: Feature.Search is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Search. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/Search. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/Search. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.Search had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.Search sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 1ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Feature.Search roles are being synced.
Info: Feature.Search role sync complete.
Info: Feature.Social is being synced.
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/templates/Feature/Social. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need
to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/Social. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps
you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Error: Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/media library/Feature/Social. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you
need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?
Warning: Feature.Social had no root paths included to sync. If you're only syncing roles, this is expected. Otherwise it indicates that your predicate has no included items and you need to add some.
Info:
Info: Feature.Social sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 2ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info:
Info:
Info: Project.Habitat.Website sync complete: 0 items evaluated, 0 items modified (0 added, 0 updated, 0 recycled) in 2ms (~2.0ms/item).
Info:
Info: Project.Habitat.Website roles are being synced.
Info: Project.Habitat.Website role sync complete.
Info:
Info: Project.Habitat.Website users are being synced.
Info: Project.Habitat.Website user sync complete.
Info:
Info: Completed.
At C:\projects\scripts\Unicorn\Unicorn.psm1:43 char:12
+ ...   $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers @{ "X-MC-MAC" = $sig ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
```

Comment: It's worth checking that you have the exact versions of Sitecore and WFFM mentioned in the setup notes. I was a minor version out, and got tripped up with a lot of similar errors.

Comment: I got the same error, my problem was that I tried to host Sitecore on a different machine than where I've got my codebase & Visual Studio. Habitat wants to serialize your items directly to disk, into your codebase (and vice versa), so they need to be on the same machine.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you ever get this resolved? Using SC9, Habitat feature/v9 branch and VS2017

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have updated the Habitat.Dev.config and set the sourceFolder to the src directory of your habitat solution.

The default location is C:\Projects\Habitat and you would expect that to be the root directory of the repository, however that is not the folder the configuration wants. It is looking for the "src" directory.

If your root git folder is C:\Projects\Habitat, then change the value of sourceFolder to the following

```
<sc.variable name="sourceFolder" value="C:\Projects\Habitat\src" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Unicorn cannot find your serialized Sitecore items. The two most obvious reasons for this would be:

- Either your Unicorn repository root folder is misconfigured. But your stack trace shows Roles being synchronised ok so this is probably less likely
- You are hitting the `path limit` of the Windows file system. This could happen if your Habitat root folder is too deep; like `C:\Windows\Users\Profile\Documents and Settings\Visual Studio Projects\Visual Studio 2015\My Local Projects\Habitat`

See also: https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn/issues/17

Comment: My project path length is as per the steps mentioned in the documentation  "https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started"

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your logs, it seems I have faced the similar issues.

The issue was resolved by using the correct versions mentioned on the sitecore github habitat repository:

https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started

Follow these steps:

- make sure you have installed the [Sitecore Experience Platform 8.2 Update 5](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Update5.aspx) ---- ([sitecore instance manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Instance_Manager.aspx) is recommended)
- Install the [Webforms for Marketers 8.2 Update 5](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web_Forms_For_Marketers/82/Web_Forms_For_Marketers_82_Update5.aspx)
- reset iis by command `iisreset` and rebuild sitecore indexes ( additional step to avoid encounter any issue).

now you have prerequisites installed for Sitecore Habitat. now run these commands one by one, I have tested it 2 or 3 times.

**Make sure you have Visual Studio 2017 installed:**

`npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools`

`npm install -g`

`npm install npm@latest`

`npm install --g gulp`

`npm install -g gulp-cli`

`npm install --save-dev gulp-sass`

`npm install node-sass -g`

`npm cache clean --f`

`npm rebuild node-sass`

**For Visual Studio 2015 follow this first**

in gulp-config.js modify `buildToolsVersion: 15.0` to `buildToolsVersion: 14.0` and run command

`npm install --msvs_version=2015 -g`

**Your prerequisites are ready, You can now run gulp from same command prompt**

`gulp`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. For me the Unicorn source folder was wrong in the config file. When updating from Habitat SC8 to SC9 (feature/v9 branch) they moved the config file. I just had to update my "sourceFolder" in Habitat.Dev.config and re-run gulp and everything worked.

Habitat Sitecore 8 config file:

```
/src/Project/Habitat/code/App_Config/Include/Project/z.Habitat.DevSettings.config
```

Habitat Sitecore 9 config file:

```
/src/Project/Habitat/code/App_Config/Environment/Project/Habitat.Dev.config
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your particular issue, but I had the same problem, and resolved it by setting the `sourceFolder` variable.

```
<sc.variable name="sourceFolder">
  <patch:attribute name="value">${Sitecore.DataDir}\Unicorn</patch:attribute>
</sc.variable>
```

Once I added this variable, the initial serialization worked

Answer (score -1):

The error in your logs is suggesting to perform the initial serialization from the Unicorn's control panel.

Access the Unicorn's control panel from the following path in your website: /Unicorn.aspx

Then click on the "Reserialize" button to perform a fresh serialization of the items defined in the Unicorn predicates configuration. This should solve your sync issue.

Also, here you can find the Unicorn's documentation: https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn

Comment: No. The Habitat solution comes with all the serialized files. Performing an initial serialization will only serialize the vanilla Sitecore to disk.

Comment: @MarkCassidy The path limit should not be a problem with Unicorn. Its serialization engine (Rainbow) takes care of this problem. The Rainbow serialization folder path length property description explains this here: https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/4433c9572e0ec1630ed1c5cc08dbdf2ee023b54e/src/Foundation/Serialization/code/App_Config/Include/Foundation/Foundation.Serialization.Settings.config
This is why I think the reserialization might fix this problem.

Comment: Yes, but if the repository was cloned to a path too deep, the files may be missing outright.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I didn't think that the Habitat items are initially created in Sitecore via the Unicorn synchronization.