# Habitat setup host name confusion

Tags: habitat, sim

In the [wiki](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started) it states that default url is http://habitat.dev.local/
and in App_Config\Include\Project\z.Habitat.DevSettings.config, it states that 
rootHostName = "dev.local"

If we implement default url name(as mentioned in wiki) using SIM. What should we give in "Site Name" and "Host Name" for local development set up? 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hostname should be habitat.dev.local on your Sim installation.

In the site definition you have:

```
<site name="habitat" patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']" 
                  targetHostName="habitat.$(rootHostName)" 
                  database="web" 
                  virtualFolder="/" 
                  physicalFolder="/" 
                  rootPath="/sitecore/content/habitat" 
                  startItem="/Home" 
                  dictionaryPath="/sitecore/content/habitat/global/dictionary" 
                  dictionaryAutoCreate="false" 
                  placeholderSettingsRoot="/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings/Project/Habitat"
                  domain="habitat" 
                  allowDebug="true" 
                  cacheHtml="true" 
                  htmlCacheSize="50MB" 
                  registryCacheSize="0" 
                  viewStateCacheSize="0" 
                  xslCacheSize="25MB" 
                  filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" 
                  enablePreview="true" 
                  enableWebEdit="true" 
                  enableDebugger="true" 
                  disableClientData="false" 
                  cacheRenderingParameters="true" 
                  renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" 
                  formsRoot="{4BC8A78C-44A7-46EB-8126-040D3F12CAA0}"
                  loginPage="/login"
                  enableItemLanguageFallback="true" />
        </sites>
```

where the hostname is a concat between **"habitat."** and the value of variable **rootHostName** wich is **dev.local** .
 The site defintion is defined in file **/src/Project/Habitat/code/App_Config/Include/Project/Habitat.Website.config**

Answer (score 0):

You can install the habitat with your desired name, SIM does not allow http://habitat.dev.local/ instead it allows http://dev.habitat.local/

You don't need to worry, You can Install it as http://habitat.local/

[image]

If you have any issue installing, follow my answer [Sitecore habitat setup](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4321/sitecore-habitat-setup/10491#10491)

Set the desired hostname `<sc.variable name="rootHostName" value="dev.local" />` in `z.Habitat.DevSettings.config` file, and run the commands to install the habitat

Once everything is finished and your sitecore and habitat is installed:

Go to IIS and add the Bindings for the http://dev.habitat.local/ 
And register the host name in the Host file as well, becuase when installing the habitat it does not register the `dev.habitat.local`

add in host file `127.0.0.1 dev.habitat.local`

[image: IIS and add the Bindings]